# Struts 2 file upload - File properties in action are null

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I read all the questions about this here on SO and I carefully followed the [official Struts 2 file upload docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload.html) but I still have the problem. The action completes without error, but I can't seem to catch the uploaded file since the 3 file properties inside the action are always null. It's like the fileUploadInterceptor doesn't do its job. Here's my code:

action mapping:

```
<action name="merchantSaveOrUpdate" class="merchantSaveOrUpdateAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">merchantList</result>
</action>
```

jsp:

```
<s:form action="merchantSaveOrUpdate" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Merchant Name</label> <input type="text" value="${merchant.name}" name="name"><br />
    <label>Merchant Logo</label> <s:file name="logo" /> <br />
    <s:submit class="btn submit" />
</s:form>
```

action:

```
public class MerchantSaveOrUpdateAction extends ActionSupport {

    private File logo;
    private String logoContentType;
    private String logoFileName;
    private String name;

    public File getLogo () {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo ( File logo ) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getLogoContentType () {
        return logoContentType;
    }

    public void setLogoContentType ( String logoContentType ) {
        this.logoContentType = logoContentType;
    }

    public String getLogoFileName () {
        return logoFileName;
    }

    public void setLogoFileName ( String logoFileName ) {
        this.logoFileName = logoFileName;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        String result = super.execute();

        // the problem is here - name is populated, but the 3 logo properties are null

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define interceptors for an action, you must define *all* interceptors for that action.

In other words, your action currently has only a single interceptor running, the file interceptor.

Note that none of the configurations on the linked page include *only* the file interceptor.

The `defaultStack` includes the file interceptor. The action can be configured like this:

```xml
<action name="merchantSaveOrUpdate" class="merchantSaveOrUpdateAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png</param>
    </interceptor-ref> 
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">merchantList</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the late accept :) I only just now got time to play with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your problem you can include the file upload.xml in struts.xml.

```
<struts>

    <include file="fileupload.xml"></include>
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <!-- file upload  -->
        <action name="upload" class="com.action.FileUpload">
    <result  name="success">success.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

This file upload.xml should be contain the interceptor ref...

```
<struts>
    <package name="fileUploadPackage" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
                      -------------
                      -------------
      <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">your file size</param>
    <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
                     ------------------
                     ------------------
                </interceptors>


    </package>
</struts>
```

And it can be done in another way also, please check this url [file upload](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/)

Comment: Seems like a lot of work for something easily handled more concisely.

Comment: That is true for the above program but below link(file upload) is easy .Actually file upload.xml will available in Google if you search we no need to type any code in that you just include that file in struts.xml with your modification(image type and size) what you would say?

Comment: I only pasted because, if you are going to develop any bigger applications on that time it is very helpful in the sense, it is present separately no need to provide the interceptors for every action.

Comment: I don't sees the point of configuring an interceptor across an entire application in this case-what if a different action needs different parameters? Your example won't work anyway since the action configuration still uses the struts-default package, not the one you've configured.